# Call a method from anywhere in a tabbar application swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I have a tabBar application with 4 different ViewControllers.
Is it possible to call the same method from all the 4 views, where do I have to put the method?
For the record it is just a call to show a iAd banner.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work.  Create a custom subclass of `UITabBarController`.  Put your function in there.  Be sure the change the class of the `TabBarController` in the Storyboard to `CustomTabBarController`.

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func myFunctionToCallFromAnywhere() {
        print("Hey, it works")
    }
}
```

Then in your viewControllers that are managed by your TabBarController you can call the function like this:

```
(self.tabBarController as? CustomTabBarController)?.myFunctionToCallFromAnywhere()
```

Comment: It does what I asked! Great thanks. Let's see if I can extend it a little bit :)